# The meaning of "sembler grecque de hasard"

Tags: sens

(M.Cartenègre put a glove on his bold head instead of a hat at the church on Sunday.)

> — Que Monsieur mette un vrai bonnet lui disait Anselmine, sa veille servante. On n'a pas idée de se coiffer d'un gant.  Mais M. Cartenègre
> n'entendait rien. Encore que détaché de bien des choses, il ne voulait
> point paraître sous un bonnet devant les habitants de la petite ville.
> **Son gant lui semblait grecque de hasard,** désinvolte, artifice improvisé.

This is from "Patachou" by Tristan Derème.

I can not understand the  meaning of "Son gant lui semblait grecque de hasard, "

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Comment: "I am sorry but but "greque de hasard" should be corrected to "grecque de hasard"

Comment: The expression doesn't make sense, it also breaks grammar.

Comment: On peut proposer que le poignet du gant était orné d'un motif grecque non conforme à la tradition, comme certains de ces bracelets https://www.qwant.com/?q=bracelet%20avec%20motif%20grecque&t=images&client=brz-moz

Comment: Ce serait alors *grec* et non *grecque* puisque *gant* est masculin. Hypothèse : une mauvaise lecture par un logiciel d'OCR? Par curiosité,  j'ai *googlé* cet ouvrage, et n'ai trouvé que des éditions anciennes, peut-être scannées,  avec les erreurs qui surviennent parfois?

Comment: @Greg — Que nenni ! Ici *grecque* = https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grecque_(motif), et les études de latin-grec étaient au programme à l'époque de l'auteur.

Comment: @personne merci, je mourrai moins bête !

Comment: @Greg — Avec une oreille plus contemporaine : « **Son gant lui semblait un** [ **motif** / **ornement** | *grecque*] [*de* | (**pris** / **dû**) **au**] **hasard, désinvolte, artifice improvisé**. » la lecture est-elle plus plausible ? — « _Son gant lui semblait un ornement dû au hasard_ … »

Comment: Thank so much for your comments. The typeface of my book is clearly typed one.  I  can definitely read "Son gant semblait grecque de hasard," Each of your comments is very helpful for me!

Comment: One could also imagine that the shape of the glove fingers formed a meandering line above his head - a *grecque*.

Answer (score 2):

Je l'entends au sens d'une calotte grecque (j'imagine assez volontiers la touche orientalisante qu'on pourrait avoir avec un gant sur la tête). "Une grecque" s'employait effectivement pour le motif (au sens "une frise grecque"), mais est tout aussi attesté pour désigner toute coiffe d'inspiration achéenne, comme le bonnet phrygien. La calotte grecque se caractérisait bien souvent par un ou des pompons, appelés glands, qu'évoqueraient par ailleurs facilement les doigts d'un gant vide. Ce que d'autres cultures appelleraient "beanie" (tout bonnet un peu informe ou pendant) aurait sans difficulté été appelé "une [calotte] grecque" en France entre la fin du XVIIIème et le début du XXème.

Le contexte me fait donc prendre "la grecque" dans cette dernière acception plus que dans celle d'une frise.

"Son gant lui semblait grecque de hasard"
=> Son gant lui formait une calotte grecque de fortune.

Source alternative d'une période proche : "Derrière lui, un petit homme noir coiffé d'une calotte grecque surgit, minuscule et grotesque".

(Pierre Souvestre et Marcel Allain, Fantômas, Les Souliers du mort, 1912, Éditions Robert Laffont, collection Bouquins, tome 5, page 982)